# Testing go channel throughput - all goroutines deadlock

Tags: concurrency, go, deadlock, goroutine

I made a small program to benchmark go channel throughput, however it always deadlocks, I tried very hard but cannot understand why:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

const CONCURRENCY = 32
const WORK_PER_WORKER = 100
const TOTAL_WORK = CONCURRENCY * WORK_PER_WORKER

func work() {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        sum *= i
    }
}

type WorkItem struct {
    Done chan int
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(CONCURRENCY)
    var workQueue [CONCURRENCY]chan *WorkItem
    // initialize workers
    for i := 0; i < CONCURRENCY; i++ {
        workQueue[i] = make(chan *WorkItem)
    }
    // start workers
    for i := 0; i < CONCURRENCY; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            anItem := <-workQueue[i]
            work()
            anItem.Done <- 1
        }(i)
    }
    completed := make(chan bool, TOTAL_WORK)
    for i := 0; i < TOTAL_WORK; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            // send work to queues
            workToDo := &WorkItem{Done: make(chan int)}
            workQueue[i/WORK_PER_WORKER] <- workToDo // !! DEADLOCK
            // wait until the work is done
            <-workToDo.Done
            completed <- true
        }(i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Waiting")
    for i := 0; i < TOTAL_WORK; i++ {
        <-completed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `go func(i int) { anItem := <-workQueue[i]; ... }` removes juste 1 item from `workQueue[i]` but you are trying to stuff WORK_PER_WORKER items into it. You will work on CONCURRENCY many items and after that all reading goroutines have terminated and you have your deadlock.

Looping in the worker goroutines "solves" your deadlock: http://play.golang.org/p/j2pavqnBDv
Just "solves" because these worker goroutines will never terminate. Maybe you can experiment with `close`ing your channels to notify the worker goroutines when nothing will be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Because your worker only process one task and then exit. Thus, only first `CONCURRENCY` items proceed and then `workQueue[i/WORK_PER_WORKER] <- workToDo` blocks indifinitely. Thus, `completed` chan never receive enough values and `main` also blocks forever.

Your worker should do work in loops, like this:

```
for i := 0; i < CONCURRENCY; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        for anItem := range workQueue[i] {
            work()
            anItem.Done <- 1
        }
    }(i)
}
```